# Initializing an instance variable in both parent and child

Tags: java

I have the following Java code

```
public class Base {
    private static boolean goo = true;

    protected static boolean foo() {
        goo = !goo;
        return goo;
    }

    public String bar = "Base:" + foo();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base base = new Sub();
        System.out.println(base.bar);
    }
}

public class Sub extends Base {
    public String bar = "Sub:" + foo();
}
```

And I'm asked what it would print. After testing this the answer seems to be `Base:false`, but I'm really unable to understand why is it not `Sub:true`.

Running through the debugger with a Breakpoint on the final print I have the following object:
[image: Debugger base]

which shows base having two variables with the same name! one having the printed Base:false and the other the expected (by me) Sub:true. Indeed foo() is called twice but each time instantiating a different variable? Shouldn't the variable with the same name created in the subclass (and initialized after the first one is created) override the one in the parent class? How does Java choose which one to print?

Comment: `base` is a reference to an instance of `Base`, so when you refer to `base.goo`, you are actually accessing `Base.goo`, not `Sub.goo`. Note that it'd work the same if you used `Base base = null;`. This is why you shouldn't access static properties of classes "through an instance": you're not using the instance at all.

Comment: @AndyTurner That I understand, what I'm interested about is the `bar` variable, which is an instance variable and is in both `Base` and `Sub`.

Comment: Ah OK. But still, `base.bar` is referring to the `bar` in `Base`, because `base` is a reference to a `Base`.

Comment: Is this not called `static binding`?

Comment: @AndyTurner so every object instantiating `Sub` would have one `bar` variable tied to the `Base` class and one tied to the `Sub` class? Will they then each be used separately in methods of the appropriate class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...which shows base having two variables with the same name!

Yup! `base` is a reference to a `Sub` instance, and that `Sub` instance has **two** `bar` fields. Let's call them `Base$bar` and `Sub$bar`:

```
        +------------------------+
base--->|      Sub instance      |
        +------------------------+
        | Base$bar: "Base:false" |
        | Sub$bar:  "Sub:true"   |
        +------------------------+
```

Java allows for the same name being used at different levels in an instance's type hierarchy. (It has to: Frequently these are *private* fields, and so a subclass may not even know that the superclass has one with the same name.)

Those two different fields in the instance have different values: `Base$bar` has the value `Base:false` because it's initialized based on the first-ever call to `foo`, which flips `goo` (which starts as `true`) and uses the flipped result. `Sub$bar` has the value `Sub:true` because it's initialized from the second-ever call to `foo`, so `goo` is flipped again and the updated value is used. There is only one instance created, but `foo` is called twice.

Which `bar` you see when you access `bar` depends on the type of the reference you have to the instance. Because `base` is declared of type `Base`, when you do `base.bar` you access the `Base$bar` field in the `Sub` instance. If you had a `Sub` reference to the instance, you'd access `Sub$bar` instead:

```
System.out.println(base.bar);        // "Base:false"
System.out.println(((Sub)base).bar); // "Sub:true"
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/atErh8)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Nescio: No worries. It wasn't quite perfect, I've corrected it (surely not perfect now either, but nothing is). There is only **one** instance created in your code. Where I said "second instance" I meant "second call to `foo`". Sorry about that.